# Авторизация, роли

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, авторизация

Всем здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться в следующих вопросах:

1. При настройке ролей в `asp.net` обязательно использовать базу данных со всеми таблицами, которые создает **`aspnet_regsql.exe`**?
2. Если использовать свою базу данных и организовывать доступ к сайту (элементам сайта) на основании ролей пользователей, то придется переписывать классы библиотеки `Security`?
3. И вообще насколько резонно использовать стандартную технологию авторизации, поставщика ролей, которые предлагает `asp.net`.
    Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИМХО, велосипеды строить нет смысла без особой необходимости. Роли не перекрывал еще, а вот MembershipProvider кастомный приходилось прикручивать так как используемая СУБД нигде не поддерживается. Если дойдет до ролей, то вероятнее всего так же кастомный провайдер сделаем и все.

Полная система авторизации и ролей довольно крупная рыба.

Comment: спасибо, буду крутить MembershipProvider